# jQuery resize() function causes stack overflow exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stack-overflow

I need to handle div resizing on my web page. The problem is that I have not idea why resize function cause stackoverflow exception. Can you explain me what am I doing wrong?

Here is a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/u9q4k4ce/

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    function start() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#divId").off('resize').on('resize', function () {
            });

            $(window).bind('resize', function () {
                $("#divId").resize();
            });
        });
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="start()">
<div id="divId" style="position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;top:0px;bottom:0px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In jsfiddle I provided any window resize cause stack overflow. I'm using newest chrome, win 7.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are creating an infinite loop which gets triggered once you resize a window. Of course, it's overflowing.

Comment: `resize` events bubbles, that's why. Stop its propagation or change your logic https://jsfiddle.net/u9q4k4ce/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/u9q4k4ce/2/

Comment: @Patel I understand that is infinite loop somewhere. My div should be resizable by user, so I would like to handle div resizing and resizing this div with entire window.

Comment: @AdamMrozek `My div should be resizable by user` So post relevant code in question itself

Answer (score 0):

Please go through https://api.jquery.com/resize/. you should pass a callback/handler to your resize().

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>Handler for .resize() called.</div>" );
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's issue

Comment: if we use the callback it does not give any error/issue.

Comment: This is window resize handler, but this div will be resizable for user. I would like to handle both operations.

Comment: But 'setting a callback' you are binding a new event, not firing it

Comment: Yes, I think you are right @A.Wolff. Its not a solution.